# How to announce network to specific neighbor peer in BGP

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, cisco-nexus

I have following scenario where i already have 10G (A - BLUE Link) connectivity from ISP on `SW1` and `SW2` for redendency and i have configured eBGP and iBGP, Everything is good at this point, Now my company need more bandwidth and more public ips so we ask for another `10G` link to our ISP which is `B` (RED Link) as per following diagram.

[image]

I have following configuration at present with BLUE link peer ( because i didn't configure RED link yet)

```
router bgp 200
  router-id 192.168.255.20
  log-neighbor-changes
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    network 74.100.100.0/23
    redistribute static route-map RTBH
  neighbor 74.1.1.10
    remote-as 100
    timers 10 30
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      send-community
  neighbor 192.168.255.19
    remote-as 200
    update-source loopback0
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      next-hop-self
```

## Question

Once i configure link `(B) RED` on SW1 & SW2 then how do i announce my new public subnet `B` for neighbor B peer?

My link B public subnet is `74.20.20.0/23` how do i tell BGP account it on link B ?

Comment: You should provide full configurations here, we can't even tell which neighbor is which from the snippet you provided. Based on what little config you're providing, any network configured with a 'network' statement would be advertised.

Comment: what other configuration you need? I believe we can use `prefix-list` to filter out route to specific neighbor for advertisement but not sure if any other method we can use

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a generic example:

```
ip prefix-list TO-A seq 10 permit 74.100.100.0/23 le 32
! 
ip prefix-list TO-B seq 10 permit 74.20.20.0/23 le 32 ! the 'le 32' allows smaller subnets of that block
!
router bgp 200
  neighbor <A>
    ip prefix-list TO-A out
  neighbor <B>
    ip prefix-list TO-B out
```

Comment: That `ip prefix-list TO-A seq 20 permit 0.0.0.0/0 le 32` is a little dangerous. It could turn them into a transit (although most providers will reject those advertisements).

Comment: True.  It's a generic example, and in the OP's example there are no filters, so that problem already exists.

Comment: I don't think that problem exists today because he only has one provider. (They'll reject transit routes because they see their own AS.) The OP does list his actual existing subnet as `74.100.100.0/23`, so that could be used in place of both seq 10 and 20.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll modify the prefix list

Comment: so we don't need any `deny` statement in prefix-list, also i had question my `A` link is live and in production so doing this exercise does cause any issue also should i need to remove `network 74.100.100.0/23` in my existing config?

Comment: Don’t forget you will need to inject the prefix into BGP in addition to filtering, so you will need a network statement for the 74.20.20.0/23 prefix as well

Comment: No, don't remove the `network` statement, since that is what's triggering the advertisement. As Karl mentioned, you will also need to add a `network` statement for the 74.20.20.0/23. Also, yes, when you apply these prefix-lists, you should do it during a maintenance window so that you can clear the BGP neighborship. To do this, the command is something similar to `clear ip bgp w.x.y.z soft out`.

Comment: In short without `clear ip bgp` it won't do anything right? i can pre-stage configuration in advance and later do clear ip bgp

Comment: @Satish that’s correct you must either hard or soft clear the bgp session before the effects of the filters go active.  I recommend going with soft clear since you don’t have to bounce the session to reannounce your prefixes

Comment: I am thinking i should load this setup in `VIRL` and give it a try there to make sure everything working as expected.

Comment: @Satish  That's probably always a good idea, so you get familiar with the commands and troubleshooting.

Comment: @RonTrunk I have question, my ISP sending `default` route over BGP, so both A & B sending default route so what default route will go in my routing table ?

Comment: look like i need Source base routing or PBR  or there is better way to handle it?